# How can I send message to all my friends who are in my roster or broadcast a message to everyone in my roster in one go, using ejabberd?

Tags: php, ejabberd, rosters

I want to send message to all contacts in my `roster` in one go. The contacts could be both online and / or offline.

Can I do this? Which modules should I enable in `ejabberd` to be able to do this? Are there any special configurations needed to be done to my server?

And if I want to do so using a `php` script, can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Please do not edit specific wordings as they have certain contextual meaning. Broadcasting a message and sending a message have different connotations, particularly when xmpp is the context. Anyway  thanks for your suggestion. Will keep note for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an announce at server level, see mod_announce.

If it's only for contacts in your roster, only for those, and they may be in several servers, then you have to rely in your client for doing that task. For example, in Tkabber's roster, when I click in a group, it shows "Send message to all the contacts in this group".

Comment: @Badlop- Hi Badlop all my contacts are in my server only. we will not allow users from other servers to login/register to our ejabberd. In that case how do I send message to all members in my roster? Is there any commandline commands to send message to everyone? What I am looking for is exactly the feature you described in Tkabber's implementation. I want to implement a similar one. If I try to do this in a loop it might end up taking a lot of time, if there are around 1000 contacts in my roster. Can I do it using python, perl or php?